# Index html generation failed. ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\

Tags: angular, npm, ng

**ng build --prod --base-href /appname/**
Option "--prod" is deprecated: No need to use this option as this builder defaults to configuration "production".
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✖ **Index html generation failed.
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\dirname\appfolder\appname-Angular12\node_modules.cache**

This error occurs when running:
ng build --prod --base-href /appname/